# como mostrar mensaje de validación con javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, function

Tengo mi formulario y lo que quiero es validar mis campos, por ejemplo que solo sean numericos, de 6 caracteres  y que si ingresan mal la informacion, se muestre un mensaje debajo del input

```html
<form: form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
  <tr>
    <td><label>ID/label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text"  id="idPago" path="id"/></td>
    <span class="error"/>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><label>CLAVE PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="clavePago" path="clavePago"/></td>
    <span class="error"/>
   </tr>



   <tr>
    <td><label>FECHA PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="fechaPago" path="fechaPago"/></td>
    <input type="submit" onclick="consultar()"></input>
    <span class="error"/>
   </tr>
</form:form>
```

tengo un codigo con javascript

```
var validator = $("#consulta").validate({ 
        rules: {
            idPago:{        
                number: true,
                maxlenght: 16
            }
        },
        messages:{
            idPago{
                 number: "El campo debe ser numerico",
                 maxlenght: "El campo debe ser de 6 posiciones"
            }

        }
})
```

pero como muestro esos mensajes debajo del input cuando no se cumple esa regla?
que propiedad uso en el input para que mande a llamar esa funcion?
es que no se muy bien como funciona esa implementacion, alguien me podria ayudar, explicar como funciona?
gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que estás utilizado jquery-validation, ¿no? https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando el id tanto en las rules, como en los messages y debes hacerlo por los name de los input prueba ponerle name al input y valida por este atributo